# What does the ^ operator do to a BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

What does this statement mean?

```
isChecked = isChecked ^ 1;
```

`isChecked` is a `BOOL`.

Comment: This is pretty straighforward to figure out. What results do you observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will XOR isChecked with 1 so I suppose true ^ 1 = 0(false) and false  ^1 = 1(true)

Answer (score 6):

The "^" is an exclusive OR operation, so 0 flips to 1, and 1 flips to zero. The result should be the same as `isChecked = !isChecked`.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is saying it XORs the bool-- that's true-- but the purpose here is that it's *toggling* the bool.

The advantage of doing a bitwise toggle like this is speed and the ability to fiddle bits in extreme detail.

for more [Bitwise Operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Answer (score 2):

It only flips the last bit of `BOOL`. Not a reliable way to logically negate.
If someone is crazy enough to set the a `BOOL` variable to some number, for example 5. Then doing `^ 1` will only flip the last bit of the value to 4, which is still evaluated to `YES`.

If you want to logically negate, use `!` operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is the [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator.

In your example it is used to create a toggle - `isChecked` will be set only if `isChecked` was previously unset.

Answer (score 1):

this is bitwise XOR operator and changes 0 to 1, and 1 to zero. see all opertors [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/objectivec-operators.html).

Answer (score 1):

"^" is called an exclusive OR or XOR operation. In this case, it will change boolean from true to false and vice-versa.

To learn more on this, check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)